# Processing 5M Records from Database to SFDC using MuleSoft as ETL

Tags: mule, batch-processing, mulesoft, mule-esb

We are using MuleSoft as the transportation layer b/w DB and SFDC and there is a use case to do one-time data migration from DB to SFDC .

DB has over 5M Records and they want push everything to SFDC. Just to mention the Mule is a stand alone server running on windows VM.

I guess to be more specific , would like to know how to retrieve the 5M records from DB ( using Mule 4) .should i fetch only 100K every time or just pull everything and set Batch Block Size to 10K. what is the best way to do it ?

Does anyone has best ideas to do this faster way ? Appreciate your thoughts on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use pagination. 100K or as many as you can per page.

Comment: I'm thinking like creating two flows.

1.Using ON TABLE ROW DB connector create the csv format as per sfdc bulk api v2.
2. Once the CSV is fully generated trigger the second flow to pick the file and send to bulk api v2.

Need to try this approach.